# How to show that f(n)*g(n) = O(f(n)*g(n))

Tags: time, big-o, proof

the exact question :

let a(n) = f(n) and b(n) = g(n).

How to prove that a(n)*g(n) = O(f(n)*g(n))

I started by assuming :
a(n) = n and b(n) = n , so based on my (hopefully reasonable) assumption i have to prove that n^2 = O(n^2).

Comment: From the definition of big O derives that: for every f: f = O(f) (f ∈ O(f) is actually more accurate because O(f) is a set).

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that *a(n) = n*, then your proof will only work for that special case, not in general for all functions *a(n)*.

I would motivate it like this:
*a(n) * b(n)* is a function too, let us call it *c(n)*.

We know that for any function, *c(n) = O(c(n))*.

Therefore it follows that *c(n) = O(a(n) * b(n)) = O(f(n) * g(n))*.